# How can I create a group and jumpping listview in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I would like to know how to do this.
I have a listview with several items in it, and I would like to order them , and separate the with headers, each one containing one letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section headers for Android ListView are described here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/

Good section headers example can be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/LabelledSections/

Sorting ListView here: http://valokafor.com/sort-listview-alphabetically-in-xamarin-android/